# LibreOffice SNAP failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: 64-bit, libreoffice, gtk, 32-bit, snap

After installing the LibreOffice 6 Snap I get this error `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`.

I `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386` but the error persists. My system is 64 bit and my Ubuntu 18.04 is 64 bits. Why is this 32 bit error occurring and what do I do about it?

Comment: And how is it a 32bit error?

Comment: googling seems to point towards that, but I am hardly an expert on the matter, perhaps an amateur

Comment: Full error message will be helpful

Comment: Flatpak and Snap are not the same thing. I think you install Libre Office via Snap by running- `sudo snap install libreoffice`

Comment: Yup - that is the full error message. If I launch LibreOffice from the terminal, my terminal spits that error message out twice.